# How do I add an alert at the end of form validation that says "Form completed correctly"?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alert

I have created a fonction that verifies and validates a form containing pseudo, email and password.

Now I would like to add a final alert to this function that takes everything into account, and if every value is correct (password is correct, pseudo has enough character, email is correct...), it displays an alert that says "Form completed".

Here is what I have in HTML

```
<form id="formNew">
                <div>
                    <p id="msgPseudo"></p>
                    <label for="pseudo">Pseudo</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div id="msgEmail"></div>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" minlength="8" maxlength="30" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <p id="msgPass"></p>
                    <label for="password"> password </label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="*******" id="password" required>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <div id="msgPassRep"></div>
                    <label for="passwordRepeat">confirm password</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="*******" id="confirm_password" required>
                    <span id='message'></span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create an account">
                </div>
            </form>
```

And the following in JS

```
function valideForm(e) {

    e.preventDefault();


    var valPseudo = document.getElementById("pseudo").value;
    var valPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var valEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var errorsPass = [];
    var errorsPseudo = [];
    var emailRegex = /.+@.+\..+/;


    let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    let numbers = '0123456789'
    let letterCount = 0
    let numberCount = 0

    for (let character of valPseudo.toLowerCase()) {
        if (letters.includes(character))
            ++letterCount
        else if (numbers.includes(character))
            ++numberCount
        else
            return false //A non [a-zA-Z0-9] character was present
    }

    if (letterCount + numberCount > 40)
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo is too long") //The name is too long
    if (letterCount + numberCount < 5)
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo is too short") //The name is too short
    if (letterCount < 1)
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo needs at least one letter") //There aren't enough [a-zA-Z] characters
    if (numberCount < 1)
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo needs at least one number") //There aren't enough [0-9] characters

    if (errorsPseudo.length) {
        alert(errorsPseudo);
    }



    if (emailRegex.test(valEmail) == false) {
        alert("please enter a valid email");
        return false;
    }


    if (!valPassword) {
        alert("Password is empty");
    }
    if ((valPassword.length < 8)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should be at least 8 characters")
    }
    if ((valPassword.length > 30)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should not exceed 30 characters")
    }
    if (!/[A-Z]/.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 uppercase")
    }
    if (!/[a-z]/.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 lowercase")
    }
    if (!/[0-9]/.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 number")
    }
    if (!/(?=.[$#%£&§@])/.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 special character")
    }
    if (errorsPass.length) {
        alert(errorsPass);
    }


    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

    function validatePassword() {
        if (password.value != confirm_password.value) {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity("passwords aren't the same");
        } else {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }

    password.onchange = validatePassword;
    confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;

}

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', valideForm);
```

How do I add this final alert that says "Form completed successfully" when every input has been verified and validated?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hey Welcome to the community.

Since you are returning `false` every time the proper rules aren't fulfilled, the execution will reach the end of the method only if all validation rules are fulfilled. Therefore you can display the `success` message at the very end.

```
function valideForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    var valPseudo = document.getElementById("pseudo").value;
    var valPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var valEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var errorsPass = [];
    var errorsPseudo = [];
    var emailRegex = /.+@.+\..+/;

    
    // check for non alphanumeric characters
    if (!/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(valPseudo)) {
        console.log("check for non alphanumeric characters -> fail")
        return false;
    }
    
    //The name is too long
    if (valPseudo.length > 40) {
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo is too long") ;//The name is too long
    }
    //The name is too short
    if (valPseudo.length < 5) {
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo is too short"); //The name is too short
    }
    // There aren't enough [a-zA-Z] characters
    if (valPseudo.replace(/[^A-Z]/gi, "").length < 1) {
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo needs at least one letter"); //There aren't enough [a-zA-Z] characters
    }
    // There aren't enough [0-9] characters
    if (valPseudo.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length < 1) {
        errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo needs at least one number") ;//There aren't enough [0-9] characters
    }
    // if errorPseudo has values then return false;
    if (errorsPseudo.length > 0) {
         alert(errorsPseudo);
        console.log("errorPseudo -> fail");
        return false;
    }



    if (emailRegex.test(valEmail) == false) {
        alert("please enter a valid email");
        console.log("Email -> fail");
        return false;
    }


    if (!valPassword) {
        alert("Password is empty");
        console.log("Password is empty -> fail");
        return false;
    }
    if ((valPassword.length < 8)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should be at least 8 characters")
    }
    if ((valPassword.length > 30)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should not exceed 30 characters")
    }
    if (!/[A-Z]/.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 uppercase")
    }
    if (!/[a-z]/.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 lowercase")
    }
    if (!/[0-9]/.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 number")
    }
    if (/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(valPassword)) {
        errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 special character")
    }
    if (errorsPass.length) {
        alert(errorsPass);
        console.log("Password rules -> fail");
        return false;
    }
    
    // check password validtiy
    if ( !validatePassword() ) {
        console.log("Password validity -> fail");
        return false;
    }
    
    // if execution can reach this line; then the form is validated
    alert("SUCCESS");

}



// moved out of the valideForm method
var password = document.getElementById("password");
var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");
function validatePassword() {
    if (password.value != confirm_password.value) {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity("passwords aren't the same");
        return false;
    } else {
        confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
        return true;
    }
}

password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', valideForm);
```

I moved the validatePassword out of the validate function because the validatePassword can function on its own. There is no need to have that inside the validate function. It makes the code more readable.

Comment: If I add this at the end of my function  "function valideForm(e)", right before the final "}", it displays it even when other value mistakes are displaying.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed code and explanations! I have one question (why move the confirm_password function ou the valideforkm method?) and one comment (unfortunately this time, the alert shows up every time, even when mistakes are made by the user in the pseudo, password or email)

Comment: @HeleneLansiaux I updated my answer again and have added console.logs where the validations fail. This is a working code.

Comment: Thank you! I will try again on my side, maybe with a different navigator. Quick question: why did you move the confirm_password function out the valideform method?

Comment: I moved the validatePassword out of the validate function because the validatePassword can function on its own. There is no need to have that inside the validate function. It makes the code more readable.